# сделать анимацию на фоновом изображении

Tags: javascript, html, css, веб-программирование, dots

Есть фоновое изображение. Как можно сделать на нем анимацию в виде двигающейся кучи шариков по заданной траектории? Что-то на подобии этого, например - https://www.ciklum.com

Помогите или примером, или советом, или статьёй, туториалом. Буду премного благодарен, так как не знаю, куда двигаться вообще.

Насколько я слышал, это называется как-то вроде `dots javascript animation`

Comment: может просто гифку запилить и не париться?

Comment: интерактивности ведь ни какой нет

Comment: Нет. Нужно именно на фон наложить всё это дело.

Comment: particle js поищите так

Comment: @StrangerintheQ я так понимаю, для новичка это нереально сделать?

Comment: @ThisMan смотрю. интересная штука

Comment: @StrangerintheQ интересно, как Вы там кольцо увидели) то есть, нужно на канве пробовать рисовать?

Comment: Спасибо. Я тоже буду пробовать)

Comment: @StrangerintheQ тут дело не в траектории и не в формуле. Тут два момента, которые нужно понять: 1. нужно понять принцип задания траектории. 2. принцип задания начальных координат множества точек. 3. задание разных цветов точкам.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Вот вроде что-то похожее получилась, вращаем точки в зависимости от их положения, времени + немного математического шума.

UPD: добавил фокусы с цветом и адаптивность

```js
// массив с вершинами, в которых будем рисовать точки
let vertices = [];
let gl = canvas.getContext('webgl');
gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, gl.createBuffer());

resize();

function resize() {
  
  canvas.width = innerWidth;
  canvas.height = innerHeight;
  
  let step = 15,
      w = Math.floor(canvas.width/step), 
      h = Math.floor(canvas.height/step);
  
 // при ресайзе заполняем массив положениями вершин
  vertices = [];
  for (var x=0; x<w*3; x++) 
    for (var y=0; y<10; y++) 
      vertices.push(1/w + x*2/w - 2, 1/h + y*2/h - 1)

  // отправляем массив с вершинами в память видео карты
  gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(vertices), gl.STATIC_DRAW);
}

// создаем новую программу для gpu, она состоит из 2х шейдеров, 
// вершинного и фрагментного
let pid = gl.createProgram();

// привязываем вершинный шейдер к программе, 
// вся соль этого примера в этом вершинном шейдере
shader(`

  // позиция вершины, которая сейчас будет обсчитываться
  attribute vec2 v; 

  // время, установленное в управляющем коде
  uniform float time; 

  // переменная, которая будет передана во фрагментный шейдер, будем
  // использовать ее чтобы задать цвет пикселей, в которые попадет данная вершина
  varying vec3 c; 
  
  // функция, которая вернет псевдослучайное число
  float rand(float n) {
    return fract(sin(n) * 43758.5453123);
  }

  // примитивная функция шума 
  float noise(float p) {
    float fl = floor(p);
    float fc = fract(p);
    return mix(rand(fl), rand(fl + 1.0), fc);
  }
  
  // поворот вдоль оси x
  mat3 rotateX(float a){
    return mat3(vec3( 1.0,     0.0,    0.0), 
                vec3( 0.0,  cos(a), -sin(a)),
                vec3( 0.0,  sin(a),  cos(a)));
  }
  
  // поворот вдоль оси y
  mat3 rotateY(float a){
    return mat3(vec3( cos(a), 0.0, sin(a)), 
                vec3(    0.0, 1.0,    0.0),
                vec3(-sin(a), 0.0, cos(a)));
  }

  // поворот вдоль оси z
  mat3 rotateZ(float a){
    return mat3(vec3( cos(a), -sin(a),  0.0), 
                vec3( sin(a),  cos(a),  0.0),
                vec3(    0.0,     0.0,  1.0));
  }
  
  // основной код вершинного шейдера
  void main(void) {
  
    vec2 p = v;
    
    // двигаем точку по y в зависимости от времени и положения по x
    p.y += sin(p.x*10.)*noise(time/1000.) + 0.5;
    
    // двигаем точку по x в зависимости от времени и положения по y
    p.x -= cos(p.y)  + sin(time/2.);
    
    // считаем итоговое положение  вершины, с учетом поворотов вокруг 
    // 3х осей в зависимости от значения функции шума и времени
    gl_Position = vec4(
      vec3(p.xy, 0.0) * 
      rotateX(p.x*3.0 + time) * 
      rotateY(noise(p.y + time/10.0)) * 
      rotateZ(noise(p.x + time/15.0)), 
    1.);
    
    // размер точки устанавливаем в зависимости от ее удаления плюс шум
    gl_PointSize = min(2.7, 1.5 + noise(time)-gl_Position.z);
    
    // ставим координату по z на 0,  чтобы избежать пропадания точек, 
    // которые при вращении как бы попали за точку наблюдателя 
    // (отрицательная z координата)
    gl_Position.z = 0.0;
    
    c = 0.2 + 0.8 * vec3(
      noise(time/2.0 + gl_Position.x),
      noise(time/3.0 + gl_Position.y),
      noise(time)
    );
    
  }
`, gl.VERTEX_SHADER);

 // привязываем фрагментный шейдер к программе
shader(`
  precision highp float;
  varying vec3 c;
  void main(void) {
      // тут все тривиально, просто устанавливаем цвет каждого 
      // пикселя в соответствии с тем значением, 
      // которое пришло из вершинного шейдера
      gl_FragColor = vec4(c, 1.);  
  }
`, gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER);

// «линкуем» программу
gl.linkProgram(pid);

// устанавливаем программу как текущую
gl.useProgram(pid);

// получаем точку привязки атрибута “v” в активной программе
let v = gl.getAttribLocation(pid, "v");

// указываем как интерпретировать данные в последнем привязанном буфере 
// со значениями вершин, который будет связан с атрибутом "v", 
// тут важно число 2, это указание сколько элементов из буфера, 
// привязано к одной вершине, 
// сейчас это 2, X и Y, тут могло быть число от 1 до 4.
gl.vertexAttribPointer(v, 2, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);

// включаем доступ к атрибуту "v"
gl.enableVertexAttribArray(v);

// получаем точку привязки переменной типа uniform с именем time,
// uniform переменные меняются только со стороны cpu, для gpu это постоянные данные
let timeUniform = gl.getUniformLocation(pid, 'time');

// запускаем цикл отрисовки
requestAnimationFrame(draw);

// вещаем слушатель на ресайз
addEventListener('resize', resize)

function draw(t) {

  // размер области отрисовки
  gl.viewport(0, 0, gl.drawingBufferWidth, gl.drawingBufferHeight);

  // цвет, которым очищается буфер кадра 
  gl.clearColor(0, 0, 0, 0);

  // устанавливаем значение переменной time
  gl.uniform1f(timeUniform, t/1000);

  // все действия до этого были сделаны в качестве подготовки для 
  // этого единственного вызова, который запускает процедуру отрисовки, 
  // тут указываем тип рисуемого примитива и их количество, сейчас это 
  // точки, еще тут могут быть линии или треугольники
  gl.drawArrays(gl.POINTS, 0, vertices.length/2);

  // запрашиваем отрисовку следующего кадра
  requestAnimationFrame(draw);
}

// функция, которая создает один шейдер и прицепляет его к программе
function shader(src, type) {
  let sid = gl.createShader(type);
  gl.shaderSource(sid, src);
  gl.compileShader(sid);
  var message = gl.getShaderInfoLog(sid);
  gl.attachShader(pid, sid);
  if (message.length > 0) {
    console.log(src.split("\n")
                   .map((str, i) => (""+(1+i))
                   .padStart(4, "0")+": "+str)
                   .join("\n"));
    throw message;
  }
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" style="background-color:black;margin:-10px"/>
```

Comment: подскажи плз литературу, что бы уметь делать такие вещи)))

Comment: @ВиталикЧерный чесслово, только математика в разрезе компьютерной графики. про сам webgl я попозже напишу небольшой пошаговый туториал как это сделано.

Comment: @ВиталикЧерный вот неплохой гайд на русском от одного из разработчиков хрома, в части webgl, который кстати активно отвечает на en.so в вопросах про webgl https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/ru/      https://stackoverflow.com/users/128511/gman

Comment: @ВиталикЧерный ну и у меня можете спрашивать ;) правда профильного образования по этой теме у меня нет, просто когда то мне стало это все жутко интересно и пока не отпустило

Comment: Как-то можно за этот ответ дать определённое количество баллов?)

Comment: @m0nte-cr1st0 это называется конкурс, но если будете его открывать, пусть неделю повисит, так этот пост увидит больше человек= ), эта опция становится доступна через 2 дня после того, как был задан вопрос

Comment: Добавить фон можно в css - `#canvas {
  background-image:url(https://i.imgur.com/aCdPKND.jpg)
}`

Comment: @StrangerintheQ, спасибо за ссылку) можно на ты если что) мы с тобой как - то общались по поводу моего вопроса. ты еще не забыл про него?))

[Как реализовать такой же эффект?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/982289/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b9-%d0%b6%d0%b5-%d1%8d%d1%84%d1%84%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82)

Comment: Подскажите, пожалуйста, как сделать более плавной траекторию, аля синусоида) Что отвечает за эти "завороты"?

Comment: @m0nte-cr1st0 это функция шума, я доберусь до компа и дополню ответ

Comment: Хорошо. Спасибо.

Answer (score 6):

Вот, что сумел соорудить, кстати.

```js
// modified version of random-normal
function normalPool(o){var r=0;do{var a=Math.round(normal({mean:o.mean,dev:o.dev}));if(a<o.pool.length&&a>=0)return o.pool[a];r++}while(r<100)}function randomNormal(o){if(o=Object.assign({mean:0,dev:1,pool:[]},o),Array.isArray(o.pool)&&o.pool.length>0)return normalPool(o);var r,a,n,e,l=o.mean,t=o.dev;do{r=(a=2*Math.random()-1)*a+(n=2*Math.random()-1)*n}while(r>=1);return e=a*Math.sqrt(-2*Math.log(r)/r),t*e+l}

const NUM_PARTICLES = 600;
const PARTICLE_SIZE = 0.5; // View heights
const SPEED = 30000; // Milliseconds

let particles = [];

function rand(low, high) {
  return Math.random() * (high - low) + low;
}

function createParticle(canvas) {
  const colour = {
r: 64,
g: 156,
b: 13,
a: rand(0, 1),
  };
  return {
x: -2,
y: -2,
diameter: Math.max(0, randomNormal({ mean: PARTICLE_SIZE, dev: PARTICLE_SIZE / 2 })),
duration: randomNormal({ mean: SPEED, dev: SPEED * 0.1 }),
amplitude: randomNormal({ mean: 16, dev: 2 }),
offsetY: randomNormal({ mean: 0, dev: 10 }),
arc: Math.PI * 2,
startTime: performance.now() - rand(0, SPEED),
colour: `rgba(${colour.r}, ${colour.g}, ${colour.b}, ${colour.a})`,
  }
}

function moveParticle(particle, canvas, time) {
  const progress = ((time - particle.startTime) % particle.duration) / particle.duration;
  return {
...particle,
x: progress,
y: ((Math.sin(progress * particle.arc) * particle.amplitude) + particle.offsetY),
  };
}

function drawParticle(particle, canvas, ctx) {
  canvas = document.getElementById('particle-canvas');
  const vh = canvas.height / 100;

  ctx.fillStyle = particle.colour;
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.ellipse(
particle.x * canvas.width,
particle.y * vh + (canvas.height / 2),
particle.diameter * vh,
particle.diameter * vh,
0,
0,
2 * Math.PI
  );
  ctx.fill();
}

function draw(time, canvas, ctx) {
  // Move particles
  particles.forEach((particle, index) => {
particles[index] = moveParticle(particle, canvas, time);
  })

  // Clear the canvas
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

  // Draw the particles
  particles.forEach((particle) => {
drawParticle(particle, canvas, ctx);
  })

  // Schedule next frame
  requestAnimationFrame((time) => draw(time, canvas, ctx));
}

function initializeCanvas() {
  let canvas = document.getElementById('particle-canvas');
  canvas.width = canvas.offsetWidth * window.devicePixelRatio;
  canvas.height = 320 * window.devicePixelRatio;
  let ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

  window.addEventListener('resize', () => {
canvas.width = canvas.offsetWidth * window.devicePixelRatio;
canvas.height = canvas.offsetHeight * window.devicePixelRatio;
ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
  })

  return [canvas, ctx];
}

function startAnimation() {
  const [canvas, ctx] = initializeCanvas();

  // Create a bunch of particles
  for (let i = 0; i < NUM_PARTICLES; i++) {
particles.push(createParticle(canvas));
  }
  
  requestAnimationFrame((time) => draw(time, canvas, ctx));
};

// Start animation when document is loaded
(function () {
  if (document.readystate !== 'loading') {
startAnimation();
  } else {
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  startAnimation();
})
  }
}());
```

```html
<canvas id="particle-canvas"></canvas>

<style>
  html, body {
    margin: 0;
  }

  #particle-canvas {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-image:url(https://i.imgur.com/HiAlf85.jpg);
  }
</style>
```

Comment: примените те же матрицы поворота и получится похоже

Comment: @StrangerintheQ подскажите, как можно выстроить точки по определённым координатам? Как на изображении, например. И чтобы они двигались в виде поверхности. Как заставить их двигаться одинаково, я понял. - https://codepen.io/m0nte-cr1st0/pen/QemJRj

Comment: Здесь, по факту две поверхности. Я так понимаю, нужно задать формулу построения точек для каждой поверхности. И формулы траектории для каждой поверхности.

Comment: @расставить их по сетке, как я вершины, я готовлю упрощенную версию своего сниппета

Comment: https://imgur.com/xw7Bm1E

Comment: https://codepen.io/strangerintheq/pen/ymKZRw?editors=0010

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1009609/188366

Comment: Здорово. Что-то получается) Подскажите, как цвет точек задать в rgba? Я так понимаю, это где-то здесь нужно указывать? `c.rgb=vec3(1.);`

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/97189/discussion-between-stranger-in-the-q-and-m0nte-cr1st0).

Answer (score 5):

Вот совместил два канваса. Наверное, это не очень хороший вариант, так как очень много схожего кода и можно как-то обойтись одним канвасом... Но нужно задать двум плоскостям разные матрицы вращения, сделать их "независимыми" друг от друга. Это первое, что на ум пришло.

```js
'use strict';
(function() {
let vertices = [];
let gl = particle.getContext('webgl');
gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, gl.createBuffer());

resize();

function resize() {
  
  particle.width = innerWidth;
  particle.height = innerHeight;
  
  let step = 10,
      w = Math.floor(particle.width/step), 
      h = Math.floor(particle.height/step);
  
  vertices = [];
  for (var x=0; x<w*3; x++) 
    for (var y=0; y<10; y++) 
      vertices.push(1/w + x*10/w - 5, 1/h + y*2/h - 1)

  gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(vertices), gl.STATIC_DRAW);
}

let pid = gl.createProgram();

shader(`
  attribute vec2 v; 
  uniform float time; 
  varying vec3 c; 

  mat3 rotateX(float a) {
    return mat3(vec3( 1.0,     0.0,    0.0), 
                vec3( -1.0,  cos(a), -sin(a)),
                vec3( 0.0,  sin(a),  cos(a)));
  }
  
  mat3 rotateY(float a){
    return mat3(vec3( cos(a), 0.0, sin(a)), 
                vec3(    0.0, 1.0,    0.0),
                vec3(-sin(a), 0.0, cos(a)));
  }

  mat3 rotateZ(float a){
    return mat3(vec3( cos(a), -sin(a),  0.0), 
                vec3( sin(a),  cos(a),  0.0),
                vec3(    0.0,     0.0,  1.0));
  }
  
  void main(void) {
    vec2 p = v;
    p.y += 0.3;
    p.x += sin(time/4. + p.y);
    vec3 pos = vec3(p.xy, 0.0)*rotateX(p.x*3. + time);
    //pos.y += sin(pos.x) - sin(time/5.)*0.5 + cos(pos.y/3.1415)*0.5;
    gl_Position = vec4(pos, 1.);
    
    gl_PointSize = 2.7;
    gl_Position.z = 0.0;
    c.rgb=vec3(1.0, 0.5, 0.0);
  }
`, gl.VERTEX_SHADER);

shader(`
  precision highp float;
  varying vec3 c;
  void main(void) {
      gl_FragColor = vec4(c, 1.);  
  }
`, gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER);
gl.linkProgram(pid);
gl.useProgram(pid);

let v = gl.getAttribLocation(pid, "v");
gl.vertexAttribPointer(v, 2, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
gl.enableVertexAttribArray(v);

let timeUniform = gl.getUniformLocation(pid, 'time');


requestAnimationFrame(draw);
addEventListener('resize', resize)

function draw(t) {
  gl.viewport(0, 0, gl.drawingBufferWidth, gl.drawingBufferHeight);
  gl.clearColor(0, 0, 0, 0);
  gl.uniform1f(timeUniform, t/1000);
  gl.drawArrays(gl.POINTS, 0, vertices.length/2);

  requestAnimationFrame(draw);
}

function shader(src, type) {
  let sid = gl.createShader(type);
  gl.shaderSource(sid, src);
  gl.compileShader(sid);
  var message = gl.getShaderInfoLog(sid);
  gl.attachShader(pid, sid);
  if (message.length > 0) {
    console.log(src.split("\n")
                   .map((str, i) => (""+(1+i))
                   .padStart(4, "0")+": "+str)
                   .join("\n"));
    throw message;
  }
}
}());

// ----------------------

(function() {
let vertices = [];
let gl = canvas.getContext('webgl');
gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, gl.createBuffer());

resize();

function resize() {
  canvas.width = innerWidth;
  canvas.height = innerHeight;
  
  let step = 10,
      w = Math.floor(canvas.width/step), 
      h = Math.floor(canvas.height/step);
  
  vertices = [];
  for (var x=0; x<w*3; x++) 
    for (var y=0; y<10; y++) 
      vertices.push(1/w + x*10/w - 5, 1/h + y*2/h - 1)

  gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(vertices), gl.STATIC_DRAW);
}

let pid = gl.createProgram();

shader(`
  attribute vec2 v; 
  uniform float time; 
  varying vec3 c; 

  mat3 rotateX(float a) {
    return mat3(vec3( -1.0,     -1.0,    0.0), 
                vec3( 0.0,  cos(a), -sin(a)),
                vec3( 0.0,  sin(a),  cos(a)));
  }
  
  mat3 rotateY(float a){
    return mat3(vec3( cos(a), 0.0, sin(a)), 
                vec3(    0.0, 1.0,    0.0),
                vec3(-sin(a), 0.0, cos(a)));
  }

  mat3 rotateZ(float a){
    return mat3(vec3( cos(a), -sin(a),  0.0), 
                vec3( sin(a),  cos(a),  0.0),
                vec3(    0.0,     0.0,  1.0));
  }
  
  void main(void) {
    vec2 p = v;
    p.y += 0.3;
    p.x += sin(time/4. + p.y);
    vec3 pos = vec3(p.xy, 0.0)*rotateX(p.x*3. + time);
    //pos.y += sin(pos.x) - sin(time/5.)*0.5 + cos(pos.y/3.1415)*0.5;
    gl_Position = vec4(pos, 1.);
    
    gl_PointSize = 2.7;
    gl_Position.z = 0.0;
    c.rgb=vec3(1., 0., 0.);
  }
`, gl.VERTEX_SHADER);

shader(`
  precision highp float;
  varying vec3 c;
  void main(void) {
      gl_FragColor = vec4(c, 1.);  
  }
`, gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER);
gl.linkProgram(pid);
gl.useProgram(pid);

let v = gl.getAttribLocation(pid, "v");
gl.vertexAttribPointer(v, 2, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
gl.enableVertexAttribArray(v);

let timeUniform = gl.getUniformLocation(pid, 'time');


requestAnimationFrame(draw);
addEventListener('resize', resize)

function draw(t) {
  gl.viewport(0, 0, gl.drawingBufferWidth, gl.drawingBufferHeight);
  gl.clearColor(0, 0, 0, 0);
  gl.uniform1f(timeUniform, t/1000);
  gl.drawArrays(gl.POINTS, 0, vertices.length/2);

  requestAnimationFrame(draw);
}

function shader(src, type) {
  let sid = gl.createShader(type);
  gl.shaderSource(sid, src);
  gl.compileShader(sid);
  var message = gl.getShaderInfoLog(sid);
  gl.attachShader(pid, sid);
  if (message.length > 0) {
    console.log(src.split("\n")
                   .map((str, i) => (""+(1+i))
                   .padStart(4, "0")+": "+str)
                   .join("\n"));
    throw message;
  }
}
}());
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
canvas {
  display: block;
}

#particle {
  background-image:url(https://i.imgur.com/HiAlf85.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
}
#canvas {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="particle"></canvas>
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 4):

И ещё два варианта

**Раз**

```js
'use strict';
(function() {
let vertices = [];
let gl = particle.getContext('webgl');
gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, gl.createBuffer());

resize();

function resize() {
  
  particle.width = innerWidth;
  particle.height = innerHeight;
  
  let step = 7,
      w = Math.floor(particle.width/step), 
      h = Math.floor(particle.height/step);
  
  vertices = [];
  for (var x=0; x<w*10; x++) 
    for (var y=0; y<8; y++) 
      vertices.push(1/w + x*10/w - 10, 1/h + y*2/h - 1)

  gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(vertices), gl.STATIC_DRAW);
}

let pid = gl.createProgram();

shader(`
  attribute vec2 v; 
  uniform float time; 
  varying vec3 c; 
    
 float rand(float n) {
    return fract(sin(n) * 4358.5453123);
  }

  // примитивная функция шума 
  float noise(float p) {
    float fl = floor(p);
    float fc = fract(p);
    return mix(rand(fl), rand(fl + 1.0), fc);
  }

  mat3 rotateX(float a) {
    return mat3(vec3( 1.0,     0.0,    0.0), 
                vec3( -1.0,  cos(a), -sin(a)),
                vec3( 0.0,  sin(a),  cos(a)));
  }
  
  mat3 rotateY(float a){
    return mat3(vec3( cos(a), 0.0, sin(a)), 
                vec3(    0.0, 1.0,    0.0),
                vec3(-sin(a), 0.0, cos(a)));
  }

  mat3 rotateZ(float a){
    return mat3(vec3( cos(a), -sin(a),  0.0), 
                vec3( sin(a),  cos(a),  0.0),
                vec3(    0.0,     0.0,  1.0));
  }
  
  void main(void) {
    vec2 p = v;
    // p.y += 0.5;
    p.y += sin(p.x*5.)*noise(time/1000.) + 0.5;
    p.x += sin(time/6. + p.y);
    vec3 pos = vec3(p.xy, 1.0)*rotateX(p.x*4. + time);
    //pos.y += sin(pos.x) - sin(time/5.)*0.5 + cos(pos.y/3.1415)*0.5;
    // gl_Position = vec4(pos, 1.);
    gl_Position = vec4(
      vec3(p.xy, 0.0) * 
      rotateX(p.x*3.0 + time) * 
      rotateY(noise(p.y + time/5.0)) * 
      rotateZ(noise(p.x + time/15.0)), 
    1.);
    
    gl_PointSize = min(2.7, 2.5 + noise(time)-gl_Position.z);
    gl_Position.z = 0.0;
    c.rgb=vec3(0.03, 0.54, 0.04);
  }
`, gl.VERTEX_SHADER);

shader(`
  precision highp float;
  varying vec3 c;
  void main(void) {
      gl_FragColor = vec4(c, 1.);  
  }
`, gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER);
gl.linkProgram(pid);
gl.useProgram(pid);

let v = gl.getAttribLocation(pid, "v");
gl.vertexAttribPointer(v, 2, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
gl.enableVertexAttribArray(v);

let timeUniform = gl.getUniformLocation(pid, 'time');


requestAnimationFrame(draw);
addEventListener('resize', resize)

function draw(t) {
  gl.viewport(0, 0, gl.drawingBufferWidth, gl.drawingBufferHeight);
  gl.clearColor(0, 0, 0, 0);
  gl.uniform1f(timeUniform, t/1000);
  gl.drawArrays(gl.POINTS, 0, vertices.length/2);

  requestAnimationFrame(draw);
}

function shader(src, type) {
  let sid = gl.createShader(type);
  gl.shaderSource(sid, src);
  gl.compileShader(sid);
  var message = gl.getShaderInfoLog(sid);
  gl.attachShader(pid, sid);
  if (message.length > 0) {
    console.log(src.split("\n")
                   .map((str, i) => (""+(1+i))
                   .padStart(4, "0")+": "+str)
                   .join("\n"));
    throw message;
  }
}
}());

// ----------------------

(function() {
let vertices = [];
let gl = canvas.getContext('webgl');
gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, gl.createBuffer());

resize();

function resize() {
  canvas.width = innerWidth;
  canvas.height = innerHeight;
  
  let step = 4,
      w = Math.floor(canvas.width/step), 
      h = Math.floor(canvas.height/step);
  
  vertices = [];
  for (var x=0; x<w*10; x++) 
    for (var y=0; y<8; y++) 
      vertices.push(1/w + x*10/w - 10, 1/h + y*2/h - 1)

  gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(vertices), gl.STATIC_DRAW);
}

let pid = gl.createProgram();

shader(`
  attribute vec2 v; 
  uniform float time; 
  varying vec3 c; 

  float rand(float n) {
    return fract(sin(n) * 43758.5453123);
  }

  // примитивная функция шума 
  float noise(float p) {
    float fl = floor(p);
    float fc = fract(p);
    return mix(rand(fl), rand(fl + 1.0), fc);
  }

  mat3 rotateX(float a) {
    return mat3(vec3( -1.0,     -1.0,    0.0), 
                vec3( -1.0,  cos(a), -sin(a)),
                vec3( 2.0,  sin(a),  cos(a)));
  }
  
  mat3 rotateY(float a){
    return mat3(vec3( cos(a), 0.0, sin(a)), 
                vec3(    0.0, 1.0,    0.0),
                vec3(-sin(a), 0.0, cos(a)));
  }

  mat3 rotateZ(float a){
    return mat3(vec3( cos(a), -sin(a),  0.0), 
                vec3( sin(a),  cos(a),  0.0),
                vec3(    0.0,     0.0,  1.0));
  }
  
  void main(void) {
    vec2 p = v;
    // p.y += 1.0;
    p.y += sin(p.x*4.)*noise(time/100.)+0.5;
    p.x += sin(time/6. + p.y);
    vec3 pos = vec3(p.xy, 1.)*rotateX(p.x*4. + time);
    //pos.y += sin(pos.x) - sin(time/5.)*0.5 + cos(pos.y/3.1415)*0.5;
    gl_Position = vec4(pos, 1.);
    
    gl_PointSize = 2.7;
    // gl_PointSize = min(2.2, 2.5 + noise(time)-gl_Position.z);
    gl_Position.z = 0.0;
    c.rgb=vec3(0.47, 0.56, 0.61);
    gl_Position.z = 0.0;
    
  }
`, gl.VERTEX_SHADER);

shader(`
  precision highp float;
  varying vec3 c;
  void main(void) {
      gl_FragColor = vec4(c, 1.);  
  }
`, gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER);
gl.linkProgram(pid);
gl.useProgram(pid);

let v = gl.getAttribLocation(pid, "v");
gl.vertexAttribPointer(v, 2, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
gl.enableVertexAttribArray(v);

let timeUniform = gl.getUniformLocation(pid, 'time');


requestAnimationFrame(draw);
addEventListener('resize', resize)

function draw(t) {
  gl.viewport(0, 0, gl.drawingBufferWidth, gl.drawingBufferHeight);
  gl.clearColor(0, 0, 0, 0);
  gl.uniform1f(timeUniform, t/1000);
  gl.drawArrays(gl.POINTS, 0, vertices.length/2);

  requestAnimationFrame(draw);
}

function shader(src, type) {
  let sid = gl.createShader(type);
  gl.shaderSource(sid, src);
  gl.compileShader(sid);
  var message = gl.getShaderInfoLog(sid);
  gl.attachShader(pid, sid);
  if (message.length > 0) {
    console.log(src.split("\n")
                   .map((str, i) => (""+(1+i))
                   .padStart(4, "0")+": "+str)
                   .join("\n"));
    throw message;
  }
}
}());
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
canvas {
  display: block;
}

#particle {
  background-image:url(https://i.imgur.com/HiAlf85.jpg);
}
#canvas {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="particle"></canvas>
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

**Два**

```js
'use strict';
(function() {
let vertices = [];
let gl = particle.getContext('webgl');
gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, gl.createBuffer());

resize();

function resize() {
  
  particle.width = innerWidth;
  particle.height = innerHeight;
  
  let step = 5,
      w = Math.floor(particle.width/step), 
      h = Math.floor(particle.height/step);
  
  vertices = [];
  for (var x=0; x<w*100; x++) 
    for (var y=0; y<8; y++) 
      vertices.push(1/w + x*5/w - 50, 1/h + y*2/h)

  gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(vertices), gl.STATIC_DRAW);
}

let pid = gl.createProgram();

shader(`
  attribute vec2 v; 
  uniform float time; 
  varying vec3 c; 
    
 float rand(float n) {
    return fract(sin(n) * 4358.5453123);
  }

  // примитивная функция шума 
  float noise(float p) {
    float fl = floor(p);
    float fc = fract(p);
    return mix(rand(fl), rand(fl + 1.0), fc);
  }

  mat3 rotateX(float a) {
    return mat3(vec3( -1.0,     -1.0,    -1.0), 
                vec3( 0.0,  -cos(a), -sin(a)),
                vec3( -1.0,  sin(a),  cos(a)));
  }
  
  mat3 rotateY(float a){
    return mat3(vec3( cos(a), -1.0, sin(a)), 
                vec3(    0.0, 1.0,    0.0),
                vec3(-sin(a), -1.0, cos(a)));
  }

  mat3 rotateZ(float a){
    return mat3(vec3( cos(a), sin(a),  0.0), 
                vec3( sin(a),  cos(a),  0.0),
                vec3(    0.0,     0.0,  1.0));
  }
  
  void main(void) {
    vec2 p = v;
    // p.y += 0.3;
    p.y += sin(p.x*5.)*noise(time/100.) + 0.2;
    p.x += sin(time/3. + p.y);
    vec3 pos = vec3(p.xy, 1.0)*rotateX(p.x*4. + time);
    //pos.y += sin(pos.x) - sin(time/5.)*0.5 + cos(pos.y/3.1415)*0.5;
    // gl_Position = vec4(pos, 1.);
    gl_Position = vec4(
      vec3(p.xy, 0.0) * 
      rotateX(p.x + time) * 
      rotateY(noise(p.y + time/5.0)) * 
      rotateZ(noise(p.x + time/5.0)), 
    1.);
    
    // gl_PointSize = 2.7
    gl_PointSize = min(1.7, 2.5 + noise(time)-gl_Position.z);
    gl_Position.z = 0.0;
    c.rgb=vec3(0.03, 0.54, 0.04);
  }
`, gl.VERTEX_SHADER);

shader(`
  precision highp float;
  varying vec3 c;
  void main(void) {
      gl_FragColor = vec4(c, 1.);  
  }
`, gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER);
gl.linkProgram(pid);
gl.useProgram(pid);

let v = gl.getAttribLocation(pid, "v");
gl.vertexAttribPointer(v, 2, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
gl.enableVertexAttribArray(v);

let timeUniform = gl.getUniformLocation(pid, 'time');


requestAnimationFrame(draw);
addEventListener('resize', resize)

function draw(t) {
  gl.viewport(0, 0, gl.drawingBufferWidth, gl.drawingBufferHeight);
  gl.clearColor(0, 0, 0, 0);
  gl.uniform1f(timeUniform, t/1000);
  gl.drawArrays(gl.POINTS, 0, vertices.length/2);

  requestAnimationFrame(draw);
}

function shader(src, type) {
  let sid = gl.createShader(type);
  gl.shaderSource(sid, src);
  gl.compileShader(sid);
  var message = gl.getShaderInfoLog(sid);
  gl.attachShader(pid, sid);
  if (message.length > 0) {
    console.log(src.split("\n")
                   .map((str, i) => (""+(1+i))
                   .padStart(4, "0")+": "+str)
                   .join("\n"));
    throw message;
  }
}
}());

// ----------------------

(function() {
let vertices = [];
let gl = canvas.getContext('webgl');
gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, gl.createBuffer());

resize();

function resize() {
  canvas.width = innerWidth;
  canvas.height = innerHeight;
  
  let step = 8,
      w = Math.floor(canvas.width/step), 
      h = Math.floor(canvas.height/step);
  
  vertices = [];
  for (var x=0; x<w*10; x++) 
    for (var y=0; y<8; y++) 
      vertices.push(1/w + x*3/w - 10, 1/h + y*2/h - 1)

  gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(vertices), gl.STATIC_DRAW);
}

let pid = gl.createProgram();

shader(`
  attribute vec2 v; 
  uniform float time; 
  varying vec3 c; 

  float rand(float n) {
    return fract(sin(n) * 43758.5453123);
  }

  // примитивная функция шума 
  float noise(float p) {
    float fl = floor(p);
    float fc = fract(p);
    return mix(rand(fl), rand(fl + 1.0), fc);
  }

  mat3 rotateX(float a) {
    return mat3(vec3( 1.0,     1.0,    0.0), 
                vec3( -1.0,  cos(a), -sin(a)),
                vec3( 1.0,  sin(a),  cos(a)));
  }
  
  mat3 rotateY(float a){
    return mat3(vec3( -cos(a), 0.0, sin(a)), 
                vec3(    1.0, -1.0,    0.0),
                vec3(-sin(a), 0.0, cos(a)));
  }

  mat3 rotateZ(float a){
    return mat3(vec3( cos(a), -sin(a),  0.0), 
                vec3( sin(a),  cos(a),  0.0),
                vec3(    0.0,     1.0,  1.0));
  }
  
  void main(void) {
    vec2 p = v;
    // p.y += 1.0;
    p.y += sin(p.x*4.)*noise(time/1000.)+0.5;
    p.x += sin(time/6. + p.y);
    vec3 pos = vec3(p.xy, 1.)*rotateX(p.x*8. + time);
    //pos.y += sin(pos.x) - sin(time/5.)*0.5 + cos(pos.y/3.1415)*0.5;
    gl_Position = vec4(
      vec3(p.xy, 0.0) * 
      rotateX(p.x + time) * 
      rotateY(noise(p.y + time/5.0)) * 
      rotateZ(noise(p.x + time/5.0)), 
    1.);
    
    // gl_PointSize = 2.7;
    gl_PointSize = min(2.7, 2.5 + noise(time)-gl_Position.z);
    // gl_Position.z = 0.0;
    c.rgb=vec3(0.47, 0.56, 0.61);
    gl_Position.z = 0.0;
    
  }
`, gl.VERTEX_SHADER);

shader(`
  precision highp float;
  varying vec3 c;
  void main(void) {
      gl_FragColor = vec4(c, 1.);  
  }
`, gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER);
gl.linkProgram(pid);
gl.useProgram(pid);

let v = gl.getAttribLocation(pid, "v");
gl.vertexAttribPointer(v, 2, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
gl.enableVertexAttribArray(v);

let timeUniform = gl.getUniformLocation(pid, 'time');


requestAnimationFrame(draw);
addEventListener('resize', resize)

function draw(t) {
  gl.viewport(0, 0, gl.drawingBufferWidth, gl.drawingBufferHeight);
  gl.clearColor(0, 0, 0, 0);
  gl.uniform1f(timeUniform, t/1000);
  gl.drawArrays(gl.POINTS, 0, vertices.length/2);

  requestAnimationFrame(draw);
}

function shader(src, type) {
  let sid = gl.createShader(type);
  gl.shaderSource(sid, src);
  gl.compileShader(sid);
  var message = gl.getShaderInfoLog(sid);
  gl.attachShader(pid, sid);
  if (message.length > 0) {
    console.log(src.split("\n")
                   .map((str, i) => (""+(1+i))
                   .padStart(4, "0")+": "+str)
                   .join("\n"));
    throw message;
  }
}
}());
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
canvas {
  display: block;
}

#particle {
  background-image:url(https://i.imgur.com/HiAlf85.jpg);
}
#canvas {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="particle"></canvas>
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Comment: переделайте на одну канву, я скидывал ссылку на кодепен где в метода draw  2 раза вызывается отрисовка сетки с разными входными параметрами

Comment: Да. определённо нужно на одну канву передлывать. Вы об этом примере - https://codepen.io/2Mogs/pen/mNdqPL?editors=0010?

Comment: https://codepen.io/strangerintheq/pen/ymKZRw?editors=0010

Comment: Что-то я не так переношу, видимо (с первого примера) https://codepen.io/m0nte-cr1st0/pen/gVjNpL?editors=0010

Comment: там отладчик ругается на шейдер в консоль

Comment: https://codepen.io/strangerintheq/pen/dxqyZM?editors=0010

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/cqyMoX3.png

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо **@StrangerintheQ** за подсказку

Решение на одной канве.

```js
let vertices = [];
let gl = cvs.getContext('webgl');
gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, gl.createBuffer());

resize();

function resize() {
  cvs.width = innerWidth;
  cvs.height = innerHeight;
  let step = 15, w = cvs.width/step, h = cvs.height/step;
  vertices = [];
  for (var x=0; x<w*3; x++) 
    for (var y=0; y<7; y++) 
      vertices.push(1/w + x*3/w - 3, 1/h + y*2/h)
  gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(vertices), gl.STATIC_DRAW);
  gl.viewport(0, 0, gl.drawingBufferWidth, gl.drawingBufferHeight);
}

let pid = gl.createProgram();

shader(`
  attribute vec2 v; 
  uniform float time; 
  uniform float shift;
  varying vec2 p;
  varying vec3 c; 

  mat3 rotateX(float a) {
    return mat3(vec3( 1.0,     0.0,    0.0), 
                vec3( 0.0,  cos(a), -sin(a)),
                vec3( 0.0,  sin(a),  cos(a)));
  }
  
  mat3 rotateY(float a){
    return mat3(vec3( cos(a), 0.0, sin(a)), 
                vec3(    0.0, 1.0,    0.0),
                vec3(-sin(a), 0.0, cos(a)));
  }

  mat3 rotateZ(float a){
    return mat3(vec3( cos(a), -sin(a),  0.0), 
                vec3( sin(a),  cos(a),  0.0),
                vec3(    0.0,     0.0,  1.0));
  }
  
  void main(void) {
    p = v;
    p.y += 0.1;
    if (shift>0.2)
        p.x += sin(time/14. + p.y);
    else
        p.x -= cos(time/4. + p.y);
    vec3 pos = vec3(p.xy, 0.0);
    if (shift>0.2)
        pos*=rotateX(p.x*6. + time);
    else
        pos*=rotateX(p.x/3. + time/1.2)
            *rotateZ(p.x/10. + time/5.);
    pos.y += sin(pos.x) - sin(time/5.)*0.2 + cos(pos.y/3.1415)*0.1;
    gl_Position = vec4(pos, 1.);
    
    gl_PointSize = 2.7;
    gl_Position.z = 0.0;
    if (shift>0.2)
        c.rgb=vec3(0.47, 0.56, 0.61);
    else
        c.rgb=vec3(0.03, 0.54, 0.04);
  }
`, gl.VERTEX_SHADER);

shader(`
  precision highp float;
  varying vec3 c;

  void main(void) {
      gl_FragColor = vec4(c, 1.);  
  }
`, gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER);
gl.linkProgram(pid);
gl.useProgram(pid);

let v = gl.getAttribLocation(pid, "v");
gl.vertexAttribPointer(v, 2, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
gl.enableVertexAttribArray(v);

let timeUniform = gl.getUniformLocation(pid, 'time');
let shiftUniform = gl.getUniformLocation(pid, 'shift');

requestAnimationFrame(draw);
addEventListener('resize', resize)

function draw(t) {

    // first grid
  gl.uniform1f(timeUniform, t/1000);
  gl.uniform1f(shiftUniform, 0);
  gl.drawArrays(gl.POINTS, 0, vertices.length/2);
    
    // second grid
  gl.uniform1f(shiftUniform, 0.5);
  gl.drawArrays(gl.POINTS, 0, vertices.length/2);
    
  requestAnimationFrame(draw);
}

function shader(src, type) {
  let sid = gl.createShader(type);
  gl.shaderSource(sid, src);
  gl.compileShader(sid);
  var message = gl.getShaderInfoLog(sid);
  gl.attachShader(pid, sid);
  if (message.length > 0) {
    console.log(src.split("\n").map((str, i) => (""+(1+i))
                   .padStart(4, "0")+": "+str).join("\n"));
    throw message;
  }
}
```

```css
body {
    overflow: hidden;
    margin:0px
}

body {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="cvs" style="background-image:url(https://i.imgur.com/HiAlf85.jpg);"/>
```